# Use Cakephp Auth component for webservices

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I'm creating a web service for android app. I'm using cakephp 3 Auth. I am getting username and password from android app in `$this->request->query['username']` and `$this->request->query['password]`.

how can I use Auth component for identifying the user?

So far I've tried is:

```
public function login(){
    if(!empty($this->request->query['username']) && !empty($this->request->query['password'])){
        $this->loadComponent('Auth');
        $user=$this->Auth->identify($this->request->query['username'],$this->request->query['password']);
        if($user){
            $this->output(['status'=>'1','message'=>'Success','user_id'=>(string)$user->id,'plan_id'=>
                    (string)$user->plan_id]);
        }else{
            $this->output(['status'=>'0','message'=>'Invalid Username/Password.']);
        }
    }    
}
```

I am getting `false` when I'm using `debug($user);` even when I'm using correct credentials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just throw stuff together and expect it to work... I mean, where do the docs say that `AuthComponent::identify()` would take username and password as arguments?

Also loading the auth component in an action is pretty pointless, as authentication would only work/be required for that single action. Again, don't just throw stuff together, read the docs, try to understand how things work, if necessary look at the source code, and *then* start coding *as shown in the docs*!

That being said, the default authenticator expects the credentials in the POST data

### Form authentication

> [...]
>
> - `FormAuthenticate` allows you to **authenticate users based on form POST data**. Usually this is a login form that users enter information
>     into.
>
> [...]
>
> **By default AuthComponent uses FormAuthenticate**.

<sup>* *emphasis mine*</sup>

**[Cookbook > Controllers > Components > Authentication](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#id1)**

So, ideally you would POST the credentials instead of passing them as query string parameters. If that isn't possible and you must use GET (you should have a good reason for that), then you could alternatively [**create a custom authenticator**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#creating-custom-authentication-objects) that fetches the data from the query, or even pass the query string data to the POST data before trying to authenticate the user,

```
$this->request->data['username'] = $this->request->query('username');
$this->request->data['password'] = $this->request->query('password');
```

that's somewhat ugly tough.

### Loading the auth component

As already mentioned, you don't load the auth component in an action, as shown in the docs, this should be done in a controllers `initialize()` method, ideally, in case the complete application should be protected, this would be the `AppController`

```
public function initialize()
{
    parent::initialize();
    $this->loadComponent('Auth', /* ... */);
    // ...
}
```

**[Cookbook > Controllers > Components](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components.html)**

### See also

- **[Cookbook > ... Components > Authentication > Identifying Users and Logging Them In](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#identifying-users-and-logging-them-in)**
- **[Tutorials & Examples > Blog Tutorial - Authentication and Authorization](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html)**

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm new to cakephp. But this helped me. I will definitely do my research next time.